# Should the headline marked with [Solved]?

Tags: discussion, site-policy

Here I had a discussion about to mark the headline with the tag [Solved]: [Rpi4B Raspbian 10 buster Adafruit-blinka Installation Problem [Solved]](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/101095/rpi4b-raspbian-10-buster-adafruit-blinka-installation-problem-solved?noredirect=1#comment166939_101095). I remember that one of the moderator has written for some time in an other comment anywhere not to do this, instead accept the answer. But I cannot find it anymore. So I looked for a policy to this in the Help Center but couldn't find anything about this. Also searching here on metha I cannot find relevant matches.

So my question: is there a policy how to handle marking headlines with [Solved]? How should this be handled?

Comment: I recently posted a comment to that end (including the request to the OP to post an answer as an actual answer instead of an edit to the question). That comment was deleted after the OP changed both. The policy - network-wide as Aurora's answer states - still stands. Thanks for bringing it up and for creating this meta-post to point out the issue here... (for those cases that future users search for it).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's a specific question on Raspberry Pi Meta, but there's a question on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/336144), the network-wide meta site, which answers this. As stated in ChrisF's answer there:

> You're right, putting "[SOLVED]" in the title is not the right thing to do.
>
> If the OP made the edit then leave a comment explaining the correct behaviour - i.e. post the solution as an answer.
>
> If someone else made the edit then roll back the edit and leave a comment addressed at the editor explaining the right thing to do.

---

While it is customary on some forums to do this, no Stack Exchange site encourages adding [SOLVED] to the title — just [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/336144), and the interface will show the question to be solved:

[image: Accepted answer]

<sup>Image from [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/336144).</sup>

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer, saves me the effort... and - as is customary - +1 for hand-drawn circle.

Answer (score 2):

It could be useful to put "[solved]" into the question title if you're about to post a self-answer afterwards. That saves the effort of people trying to answer the question before the self-answer is posted.

Once the self-answer is there, one could remove the "[solved]" tag to make the question look normal.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange sites fill the box with the question score or the number of answers on questions with accepted answers in green anyway. The only use of it would be for people who don't use the site but want answers for their questions because they wont know that the tick mark means accepted until they hover over it. Other forums might not have a button equivalent to the accept button which is why it might be customary there. Also you can answer your own question when you're submitting your question so that removes the use case stated by Dmtry.

[image: Screenshot of Ask a public question page]